# Mongoose embedded document updating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I have a problem with embedded document update.

My defined Schemas:

```
var Talk = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    comments: {
        type: [Comments],
        required: false
    },
    vote: {
        type: [VoteOptions],
        required: false
    },
});

var VoteOptions = new Schema({
    option: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    count: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    }
});
```

Now I would like to update `vote.count++`, with given `Talk` id and `VoteOption` id. I have the following function to do the job:

```
function makeVote(req, res) {

    Talk.findOne(req.params.id, function(err, talk) {
        for (var i = 0; i < talk.vote.length; i++) {
            if (talk.vote[i]._id == req.body.vote) {
                talk.vote[i].count++;

            }
        }
        talk.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                req.flash('error', 'Error: ' + err);
                res.send('false');
            } else {
                res.send('true');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Everything executes, I get back the `res.send('true')`, but the value on count does not change.

When I did some `console.log` I saw that it changed the value, but the `talk.save` just doesn't save it in db.

Also I'm quite unhappy about the cycle just to find `_id` of embedded doc. In the mongoose documentation I read about `talk.vote.id(my_id)` but that gives me error of not having an `id` function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When updating a `Mixed` type (which seems to be anything else than a basic type, so that also includes embedded documents), one has to call `.markModified` on the document. In this case, it would be:

```
talk.markModified("vote"); // mention that `talk.vote` has been modified

talk.save(function(err) {
    // ...
});
```

Hope this helps someone in the future since I couldn't find the answer very quickly.

---

[Reference:](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

> ... Mongoose loses the ability to auto detect/save those changes. To "tell" Mongoose that the value of a Mixed type has changed, call the `.markModified(path)` method of the document passing the path to the Mixed type you just changed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to save your talk object before the callback which increments count has been fired. Also, did you make sure to instantiate your Talk schema? eg:

```
var talk = new Talk();
```

However, if all you want to do is increment your count variable, mongo supports atomic, in-place updates which you may find useful:

```
talk.find( { _id : req.body.vote }, { $inc: { count : 1 } } );
```

have a look at:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc