# Check if Obejct is Empty: Mongoose Nested/Embedded Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my documents pre save hook, I check if all the properties from the nested property `accident` exist and have correct values. If `accident` does not exist at all this is also fine.

When I'm trying to save a doc which has no value on the nested property `accident` of my doc it still goes into my custom validation rules. This is because I fail to detect if this nested object is empty.

### Property in the Schema

```
prescriptionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  accident: {
    kind: String, #accident, workAccident,
    date: Date,
    company: String
  },
  ...
```

### Pre Save Hook

```
console.log _.isEqual(data.accident, {}) #false
console.log JSON.stringify data.accident #{}
console.log JSON.stringify data.accident == JSON.stringify {} #false
console.log JSON.stringify {} #{}
console.log Object.keys(data.accident).length #14
for key, value of data.accident
  console.log key, value #gives me basically the whole document with functions etc.
```

### Current Detection (not good code)

```
if data.accident? && (data.accident['kind'] || data.accident['date'] || data.accident['company']) #=> do validation
```

## Seed

```
  newRecipe = new RecipeModel()


  for key, value of recipe
    newRecipe[key] = value

  newRecipe.save((err, result) ->
    return next err if err?
    return next "No Id" if !result._id?
    return next null, result._id
  )
```

I tried `{}`, `null` and nothing as values for `recipe.accident`.

Mongoose Version: `4.0.2`
Node Version: `5.9`

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked although I now have `_ids` on the embedded objects which I don't need.

I moved out the object from the main schema and defined it as a own sub schema:

```
drugSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  exchangeable: Boolean
})

accidentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  kind: String, #accident, workAccident,
  date: Date,
  company: String
})

prescriptionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  drugs: [drugSchema],
  dutiable: Boolean,
  accident: accidentSchema,
  ...
```

After this, the object is undefined in the pre save hook.

Answer (score 0):

By default, *mongoose* won't save empty objects. You need **to disable the *minimize* option** in your Schema.

```
prescriptionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    accident: {
        kind: String, #accident, workAccident,
        date: Date,
        company: String
    }, 
    ... 
}, {
    minimize: false
})
```

**Source :** http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#minimize

**UPDATE :** If it is not saving the object, you can try to use the `markModified()` method (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed).

And for your checking problem, you can perform a function which will check your fields. Here's two examples : https://jsfiddle.net/ew2um2dh/13/

Comment: Actually it is not saving the object as you mentioned but I'm fine with that. Maybe I didn't ask specifc enough what I try to accomplish: I want to return an error in my pre saving hook if one of the nested properties is empty but not all of them are empty. At the moment I check if the object exists: if `data.accident? && (data.accident['kind']? || data.accident['date']? || data.accident['company']?)`which is not very beautiful code in my opinion. Then I check if all properties are there and if they have correct values.

Comment: I would like to refactor the above check to some of the expressions in the `console.log` examples. Also I would like to understand why the object is not an empty object in the pre save hook/behaves like that.

Comment: Hi I didn't want to use `Mixed` because I know the structure of the sub object. I tried the `markModified ` which didn't work for me. But this lead me to another post and to a solution I can live with:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002145/mongoose-embedded-document-updating
I don't even need to call the `markModified` `function` but I have `_ids` I don't really require now.